# Calcular Mantenimiento preventivo de automovil en JavaFX

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

Antes que nada buen dia a todos!.

Bueno hoy tengo un pequeño problema a resolver con un programa que se me solicito desarrollar en Java se trata de calcular la Cifra en kilometraje que a un auto debe realizarsele **mantenimiento**.
Por ejemplo a cada automovil se le realiza mantenimiento a los **5,000 Km**. Lo que quiere decir que un auto con un kilometraje actual de **10,000 Km** debe ir a mantenimiento a los **15,000 Km**.
Se enviar las **alertas** segun el valor del campo **kilometraje actual**. Pero mi profesora quiere ver un campo que muestre el **kilometraje** en el que el auto debe ir a mantenimiento en **base a 5000 Km**.
Ejemplo:

- **Auto:** Toyota Corolla
- **Placa:** A121212
- **Km Actual:** 5500
- **KmProxMantenimiento:** ?
  Aqui muestro mi interfaz lo que esta encerrado en Rojo es el dato que utilizo estatico para calcular cuando ya ha recorrido los 5000 kilometros.

5000 en el circulo rojo es la base para calcular el recorrido de 5000 kilometros y enviar las alertas pero como dije anteriormente a¿la profesora quiere ver el kilometraje proximo segun el kilometraje actual o como yo lo he puesto KmFinal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo:

```
@FXML
public void RE() {
    try {

        Integer n1 = Integer.parseInt(txt_KmIni.getText());//Kilometraje Inicial de la jornada
        Integer n2 = Integer.parseInt(txt_KmFin.getText());//Kilometraje Final fin de jornada
        Integer resta1 = n2 - n1;//Resta de Kilometraje final menos inicial = Kilometraje Recorrido durante la jornada
        String total1 = Integer.toString(resta1);
        txt_KmRec.setText(String.valueOf(total1)); //Total asignado al campo Kilometraje Recorrido

        Integer Recorrido = Integer.parseInt(txt_KmRec.getText()); //Campo Kilometraje recorrdio
        Integer RecorridoTtal = Integer.parseInt(txt_KmRecoTotal.getText());//Campo Kilometraje Recorrido Total por cada vahiculo Proviene de suma en MySQL
        Integer ProxMantenimiento = Integer.parseInt(txt_ProxMant.getText());//Campo con valor de proximo mantenimiento en este caso 5,000 como base

        Integer Calculado1 = Recorrido + RecorridoTtal; //Recorrido del dia + Recorrido Total del vehiculo -> (Dato de MySQL)
        Integer Calculado2 = ProxMantenimiento - Calculado1;//Resta del campo Proximo Mantenimiento - Calculado1 que es la suma del kilometraje recorrido del dia mas el total del vehiculo
        txt_KmRest.setText(String.valueOf(Calculado2)); //Aqui es donde seteo el resultado de Calculado2 que es el kilometraje restante para el proxmantenimiento segun esto envio alertas.

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido. Tu pregunta es muy amplia aun. ¿Estas trabajando con GUI y ahí quieres ver el campo? ¿En que parte de tu código tienes duda? Sería bueno que editaras la pregunta (hay un link para eso) y agregues más información. Puedes editar las veces que sea necesario. También sería bueno que pusieras la estructura de tus tablas y algúnos datos de ejemplo que esten relacionado con el problema que tienes.

Comment: Asi es utilizo GUI tengo una interfaz grafica. Agregare mas info

Comment: Muestra tu código donde haces el cálculo de la proxima revisión

Comment: Ok un momento voy

Comment: Por lo visto almacenas el dato Próximo Mantenimiento. Puedes hacer un update y sumarle `5000` de esta manera solo agregaras una cuantas lineas más. Esto lo haces en la operación donde almacenas el nuevo kilometraje.

Comment: Si no lo quieres almacenar solo toma el kilometraje actual y metelo en una operación y hacen un bucle que ta vaya multiplicando por 5000. En cada iteración comparas `KM Recorrido<nuevoKilometrajeMant`, si se cumple `nuevoKilometrajeMant+=5000` y cuando no se cumpla lo imprimes en pantalla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener el proximo mantenimiento puedes hacer esto

Dividir el número total hacía abajo entre 5000, después sumarle uno y multiplicarlo por 5000, por último restarle la cantidad actual,

5500/ 5000 (redondeado hacía abajo) = 1;
1 + 1 = 2;
2 * 5000 = 10000; (la próxima actualización);
10000 - 5500 = 4500 (cuanto falta)
Esto podría quedar en java así

```
Integer Calculado1 = Recorrido + RecorridoTtal; //Recorrido del dia + Recorrido Total del vehiculo -> (Dato de MySQL)
float maintenanceNum = Calculado1 / 5000
int nextMaintenance = (Math.round(maintenance) + 1) * 500; // te dirá el km de tu próximo mantenimiento, ya sea 5,000 10,000
int kmToMaintenance = nextMaintenance - Calculado1; // te dirá los km restantes para mantenimiento
```

Consejo: por buenas prácticas de programación las variables se definen con loweCamelCase, es decir la primera letra en minúscula, solo las clases se definen con UpperCamelCase. si no vas a usar el int como clase úsalo de forma primitiva (int en lugar de Integer);

Comment: Probando Gracias! tomo nota!